# SQL Server - Close external port and work as localhost when sql server and application are on the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

My database and my web application are at the same server at the moment and I would like to access SQL Server as `localhost` and **close** **the** **SQL Server port for remote connections.**

This is my current connection string, how can I modify it so it will access the database from as `localhost`?

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:152.242.211.112;Initial Catalog=testdb;User ID=usera;Password=********"
}
```

I tried:

```
server=(local)
tcp=127.0.0.1
Data Source=(local)
```

using `Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS`
I got this message:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Comment: Try `server=(local);` etc if it is not a named instance. [This](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) is a good source for patterns.

Comment: I get an error `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

Comment: Try your local tcp address `127.0.0.1` instead

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses the magic string `(local)` instead of `localhost` - this is because SQL Sever can use transports other than TCP/IP for connecting to the server instance (like Named Pipes and Shared Memory) whereas the hostname `localhost` is specific to TCP/IP.

So use `Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=...` in your connecting string.

Comment: I try this and I get:
`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)` error

Comment: That message says it’s using Named Pipes. Open MMC and load the SQL Server Configuration Manager snap-in and ensure Named Pipes are enabled. Also enable the SQL Server Browser service. Also you need to add the Instance Name to the connection string if you’re using a named instance (like `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`).

Comment: I followed this video that explained what you adviced and in the end I got this error message:
`A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)`